# Define condition hightlighting in correct cell

Tags: conditional-statements, jscript

```js
function myFunction12(){
    var table1 = document.getElementById("table1").rows; 
    var y31;
    for(var i = 2; i < table1.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 4; j < 5; j++) {
            y31 = table1[i].cells;
            if((y31[j].innerText)>="79 %") {
                y31[j].style.backgroundColor ="red";
            } else if(((y31[j].innerText)>="80 %") && ((y31[j].innerText)<="89 %")) {
                y31[j].style.backgroundColor ="YELLOW";
            } else if((y31[j].innerText)>="90 %") {
                y31[j].style.backgroundColor ="GREEN";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above jscript selects a table value and highlights it if a condition is satisfied, but as per define condition highlighting in correct cell.

```js
function myFunction12(){
    var table1 = document.getElementById("table1").rows; 
    var y31;
    for(var i = 2; i < table1.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 4; j < 5; j++) {
            y31 = table1[i].cells;
            if((y31[j].innerText)>="79 %") {
                y31[j].style.backgroundColor ="red";
            } else if(((y31[j].innerText)>="80 %") && ((y31[j].innerText)<="89 %")) {
            y31[j].style.backgroundColor ="YELLOW";
        } else if((y31[j].innerText)>="90 %") {
            y31[j].style.backgroundColor ="GREEN";}
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have never dealt with this technology before but perhaps the space between `"79` or `"80` and `"90` and the `%"` is problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working suggestion:

```
function myFunction12() {
    var table1 = document.getElementById("table1").rows;
    var y31;
    for (var i = 2; i < table1.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < table1[i].cells.length; j++) {
            y31 = table1[i].cells;
            if ((y31[j].innerText) >= 79) {
                y31[j].style.backgroundColor = "red";
            } if (((y31[j].innerText) >= 80) && ((y31[j].innerText) <= 89)) {
                y31[j].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            } if ((y31[j].innerText) >= 90) {
                console.log(y31[j].innerText, (y31[j].innerText) >= 90)
                y31[j].style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed "79 %" to a number 79 and all other numbers as well (because otherwise you will never get true on "79" >= "79 %").
Also I have changed conditions from "else if" to "if". because all numbers which are bigger than 79 will fall under that condition, and your code will not proceed.